# How to exernalize @emotion/react, and @emotion/styled for Create React App

Tags: reactjs, webpack, emotion, micro-frontend, css-in-js

I have the following architecture:

- main-frontend
- foo-frontend
- bar-frontend
- baz-frontend

`main-frontend`, `foo-frontend`, `bar-frontend` and `baz-frontend` are all standard React apps generated using `create-react-app`.

All of them except `main-frontend` publish their UI as a React component, wrapped in a Web component. These Web components can be loaded into the `main-frontend` to weave all 3 sub-frontends into one super-frontend.

The problem I am facing is that in order for this approach to work, all 4 frontends have to externalize `react`, `react-dom`, `react-router`, and any CSS-in-JS frameworks being used.

I am able to modify Webpack configuration for `create-react-app` generated React apps, using the `rewire` package and a couple of scripts. I am reproducing these below for others facing a similar problem.

In each of `foo-frontend`, `bar-frontend`, and `baz-frontend`,

**package.json**

```json
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "rewire": "^6.0.0"
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node start.js",
    "build": "node build.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "webpackConfig": {
    "externals": {
      "react": "react",
      "react-dom": "react-dom",
      "@emotion/react": "@emotion/react",
      "@emotion/styled": "@emotion/styled"
    }
  }
```

**build.js**

```js
const rewire = require('rewire');
const defaults = rewire('react-scripts/scripts/build.js');

const {
  webpackConfig: {
    externals
  }
} = require('./package.json');

const config = defaults.__get__('config');

config.externals = externals;
```

**start.js**

```js
const rewire = require('rewire');
const defaults = rewire('react-scripts/scripts/start.js');
const webpackConfig = require('react-scripts/config/webpack.config');

const {
  webpackConfig: {
    externals
  }
} = require('./package.json');

defaults.__set__('configFactory', (webpackEnv) => {
  const config = webpackConfig(webpackEnv);

  config.externals = externals;

  return config;
});
```

**public/index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...
    <title>Atlas Reviews</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@emotion/react@11.9.0/dist/emotion-react.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@emotion/styled@11.8.1/dist/emotion-styled.umd.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  ...
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem I am getting is that `@emotion/react` and `@emotion/styled` aren't being externalized correctly.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: emotion is not defined
    at Object.@emotion/react (external var "emotion":1:1)
    at Object.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at Module../src/components/App/styles.tsx (index.tsx:25:1)
    at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at Module../src/components/App/index.tsx (logo.svg:34:1)
    at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this, not with `@emotion/react` and `@emotion/styled`, but with `styled-components`.

To be fair, that was my initial preference for a CSS-in-JS framework.

In my previous attempts, I had been using the wrong version of the `styled-components` library.

Here's how I managed to do it:

**package.json** in all 4 React apps should be modified like so.

```json
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.25",
    "rewire": "^6.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=3004 node start.js",
    "build": "PORT=3004 node build.js",
    "test": "PORT=3004 react-scripts test",
    "eject": "PORT=3004 react-scripts eject"
  },
  "webpackConfig": {
    "externals": {
      "react": "React",
      "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
      "react-is": "ReactIS",
      "styled-components": "styled"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

**public/index.html** in the 3 sub-frontends should be modified like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...
    <title>Atlas Reviews</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-is@18.1.0/umd/react-is.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/styled-components@5.3.5/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
  ...
  </body>
</html>
```

The `public/index.html` for the super-frontend will be similar, but will also include `script` tags to import the sub-frontends:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...
    <title>Atlas Reviews</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-is@18.1.0/umd/react-is.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/styled-components@5.3.5/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:3003/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
  ...
  </body>
</html>
```

**TL;DR;**: Note the externals for `react-is` and `styled-components` and the version of the `styled-components` script being loaded via CDN.